# overflow:hidden appears to do nothing?

Tags: css

So I have a containing element whose width gets smaller as the screen get smaller `#Aa`, this element has a `<nav>` element that contains a `<ul>` element and some `<li>` elements as menu items.

When `#Aa` can no longer contain all the `<li>` elements the page layout is broken.

What I would like to happen is what is suppose to happen when

`overflow:hidden` is used.  I applied this rule to `#Aa`.

I thought this was the purpose of `overflow:hidden`.  I entered it manually through the web inspector.

Here is **some** of the relevant CSS

```
nav {
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: right;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 60px;
    color: #2e2c60;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}
nav ul li:hover{
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
nav ul li:last-child{
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: You should post your relevant code, it will help use determine your problem without having to guess.

Comment: What is the actual problem here? Is it that the list drops onto the next line when the screen is small? And what is the actual desired outcome. Just saying "what overflow: hidden is supposed to do" is pretty vague. I mean I know what overflow: hidden is supposed to do, but you don't explain what you actually want.

Comment: specify height for <nav> along with overflow:hidden property

Comment: The overflow does work correctly for me in the live version using Chrome (44.0). If what you're trying to achieve is a compressed navigation system, you'll need to style it accordingly with media queries or dropdown logic, for example.

Comment: Are you trying to get it flow without overlapping the container? Remove the height off of A and Aa. Overflow hidden with floating elements if a height is set.

Answer (score 0):

```
element {
    display: none;
}
```

Try removing this from the inline style of the `#left-column` element:

```
<section style="display:none;" id="left-column">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code,

```
 nav {
           float: right;
    width: 75%;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

and add `float:left` to logo image

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll have to put codes for "nav" according to the resolution in your media queries.

Comment: You're trying to view it at lesser resolution that's why it's broken. You should add desired "nav" codes on each media queries. You can find it on your css page by typing "@media screen"

Comment: Its because of the resolution as I said. When your browser's resolution will be more than 913px, it'll show up the navigation else it'll be knocked down. Just add media queries for you nav element.

Comment: You can add the following to get rid of this as long as your browser's resolution will be 774px or more :

nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 60px;
    color: #2e2c60;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
}

Answer (score 0):

**In short:**
You need to define the `height`, or `max-height` (more suitable for this example) in order for overflow to work, otherwise it would just expand, since is the expected behavior